# Seam conversation

Tags: seam

I am trying to create a form with 3 drop downs and a text area. I am using conversation as scope. I end the conversation when user click on submit button. The problem that I am facing is back button issue. When back button is clicked, previous data is remembered. If I try to select from a drop down, I get a message that conversation has ended. Is there a way I can just reload the page from scratch? So, users can submit a new request?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create where to redirect a conversation in the `pages.xml` configuration file scratch

```
<pages>
  <page view-id="/youfile.xhtml" no-conversation-view-id="/scratch_form.xhtml"">
  </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Form page is named, createRequest.xhtml. Coversation is started when a page is loaded, and ended when user clicks submit. When user clicks submit, it is redirected to viewRequest.xhtml. Clicking back button takes user back to createRequest.xhtml. When that happens I want new conversation to start and empty previous selections.
So, will following achieve that?
    <page view-id="/viewRequest.xhtml" no-conversation-view-id="/createRequest.xhtml"">
    </page>